# Unable to download files with .7z extension from server

Tags: download, 7zip

I have uploaded the files with extension .7z and .zip, "test.7z" and "test.zip" to our server.

When i tried to download "test.zip" it will download

[files2.syncfusion.com/dtSupport/DirectTrac/95453/test.zip](http://files2.syncfusion.com/dtSupport/DirectTrac/95453/test.zip)

But i cant download "test.7z" file.

http://files2.syncfusion.com/dtSupport/DirectTrac/95453/test.7z

Why cant i download 7z files from server? Is this default behavior or i need to set any MIME type in server. Can any one give me solution for this?

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: I can download your .7z file.

Comment: Probably this just depends on a browser.

Comment: We need to add MIME type for 7 zip files in files2 server. MIME type for  .7z is “application/x-7z-compressed”.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried downloading the .7z file with different browsers. The result makes me think that it's more to do with those than the server configuration, though setting a MIME type is always worth a try.

One thing that might make you happy is that the download works just fine in *Safari*.

*Firefox*, *Internet Explorer* and *Chrome* allow the download if you use *right click & save as*.

Only *Opera* will not allow you access to the file at all.

If nothing else you try works you could always add a small not to please use one of the working browsers and the save as option.